# Incorrect JAVA version in command prompt, only one installed?

Tags: installation, java-8, path, environment-variables, java-21

I have installed things like visual studio code. I have a 64 bit computer. I am trying to install JAVA jdk for a class. The prof told us to install 1.8.0_281 since he said it is the latest that is also free. I don't think I have ever installed JAVA before, and when I search in my apps, it only has one JAVA, which is the right version according to its about page. However when I go into the command prompt it says
java version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17 LTS
[image is of the result when I try to get JAVA version in command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu2NW.png)
It does compile and run programs (JAVA)
Also, the prof told us to add
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281\bin
as a path and delete other paths in environment variables
[other paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IuWj.png)
but when I delete the other one (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath), then ask the command prompt for JAVA version, the command prompt says:
Can no longer access java in command prompt, says java is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program, or batch file

I deleting and reinstalling java, as well as turning my comp off and on
I didnt pay for anything I'm pretty sure, so I dont see how it is possible I have JAVA 21
I'm using windows 10

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood your Professor. Java 21 is the latest Java version, and you can download it for free (which you did). If you want to download an old Java version, you can try this page - https://www.oracle.com/il-en/java/technologies/downloads/archive/

Comment: I believe you but I dont understand then why when I go to my apps I dont see Java 21

Comment: and also, i did go to that page and download java 8 281, and how do I use that version? I dont want to have something work for my new version of Java then miss points on an assignment because it doesnt work on the version of java my professor is grading on

Comment: I figured my problem, when I reinstalled, the install told me what folder it was going to and it is not the same as the path he specified

Comment: Your prof is a bit outdated. The JDK version you mention is the last free Oracle Java version that can be used for commercal purposes (for open source it was always free), but all the alternative JDKs are still free. Oracle also recognized a few years later that the license restriction wasn't very effective with free versions around so in recent Java versions (AFIR JDK 21+) the life se was changed back to "free".

Comment: Just replace the value the professor gave you with the one of the JDK you installed to… Don't remove any other value in the path or you may have problems.

Answer (score 1):

Having Java "installed" vs having it on disk and pointed to by your PATH are not equivalent things. Long ago, when web browsers used a java plug-in, the concept of installation applied to Java. But for the past several years, having the JDK on disk and adding it to the PATH is all that is needed. It is normal for it to not show up in your list of installed apps.

As far as how Java 21 got onto your machine, who knows. But it's the latest version, and it should be completely fine to use for educational purposes since Java 21 is largely backwards compatible with Java 8.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).